# Select where a column value is included in a string (or array)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

**js**

```
let ids = $.map($('.atitle'), (e) => $(e).attr('data-id'));
console.log(ids);
// ['6493e687161e0', '64a6776077613', '6489c85b3e6b1']
$.post('index_pro.php', {fn: 'btn_mails', args: [ids]}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //  error
});
```

**error:**

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1367 Illegal double '6493e687161' value found during parsing in...
```

**php**

Need to select distinct `mail` where `mail` is not empty and `id` is in the above array

```
function btn_mails($ids){
    global $db;
    $str = implode(', ', $ids);
    $sq = "select distinct mail from arts where mail <> '' and id in (" . $str . ")";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute();
    $arr = $st->fetchAll();
    $str = '';
    foreach($arr as $el){$str .= $el['mail'] . "\n";}
    $str = rtrim($str, "\n");
    echo $str;
}
```

Comment: You want `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, :ids)`

Comment: You shouldn't put space after the comma in `$str`.

Comment: The reason for your error is because you didn't put quotes around the array elements when you created `$str`. So it's trying to parse them as numbers, but they're not valid numbers.

Comment: If you had done `echo $sq` you would have seen the problem

Comment: @Barmar - you probably mean -` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, :str)`. Anyway, solved, thanks a lot

Comment: I intended that you would do `bindParam(':ids', $str)`